# ReactJS: Conditional rendering submits form data before handleSubmit function

Tags: reactjs

I have a form that upon completion renders a button with form data.
The form takes two inputs: 1. Title (text rendered in button) & 2.) URL for the button.

The form works with the conditional statement if I paste in a URL. However if I begin manually typing a URL, it generates the button based on the first character I type because the string is no longer empty.

```
export default class URLButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      links: [],
      url: '',
      title: ''
    }
  }

// onChange
  onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(e)
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  // onSubmit

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.url === "") {
      return (
        <>
          <form onClick={this.onSubmit}>
            <input
              name="title"
              type="text"
              placeholder="add button text"
              onChange={e => this.setState({ title: e.target.value })}
            />
            <input
              name="url"
              type="url"
              placeholder="your-link.com"
              onChange={e => this.setState({ url: e.target.value })}
            />
            <br />
          </form>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <div>
            <a href={this.state.url} className="link-button" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{this.state.title}</a>
          </div >
        </>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Since the onChange and onSubmit function works, I've narrowed it down to the conditional statement `if (this.state.url === "") {...` I've tried setting it to `null` and `false` instead of an empty string but the form doesn't render if I try those statements.

Comment: `<form onClick={this.onSubmit}>` Did you mean `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you're right, your problem is that, when you typed something, the `url` state is not empty anymore, you'll have to validate that the `url` is valid in order to submit the form, I've made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xwxof7) with the solution of the problem, I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Alberto, this soltion almost works except when I enter the second letter after the period in the url, it stops typing and submits the data. Example: I'm typing facebook.com & it stops at facebook.c

Comment: @RHBlanchfield I've edited my answer in order for you to be able to type the complete URL, but you'll have to set how many characters do you want to validate for it, in this line: '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{3,}|'+ // domain name

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. I'm new to React/JS and doubt I could have figured out that solution.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad that it helps you @RHBlanchfield :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to finish typing and than generate the button 
you can change your onChange to onBlur as

```
<input
   name="url"
   type="url"
   placeholder="your-link.com"
   onBlur={e => this.setState({ url: e.target.value })}
/>
```

Now when you type out and blur out of input than button will be gernerated

Hope it helps

Comment: Great! This fixed the issue along with Alberto Perez's StackBlitz

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should pass yours input states to input:

```
...
<input
   name="url"
   type="url"
   value={this.state.url} // here
   placeholder="your-link.com"
   onChange={e => this.setState({ url: e.target.value })}
/>
...
```

By this edit onChange would pass to set state not only character you've just wrote, but all of previous charecters plus last one.

Then look at your code here:

```
...
if (this.state.url === "")
...
```

It would be false right after the FISRT charecter in state.url setted.
If you need to check for correct URL you should use regexp in if condition, to check if state.url looks like correct url by your expectations and ONLY after that render the other part of component.